# Reputation shown different in Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, support, bug, association-bonus, caching

I created a new account in Meta Stack Exchange and it give me `+100` bonus points which displayed on `Meta Stack Exchange` account like so:

<kbd>[image: META rep display]</kbd>

In Stack Overflow my profile displays `1` as reputation for `Meta Stack Exchange` account like so:

<kbd>[image: SO version of META rep]</kbd>

Why display different reputation in these accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking again now. Here is what it looks like to me:

[image]

Completely correct.

Reputation takes time to update between websites. You just hadn't waited long enough. You see this sometimes even between SO and MSO - there is a time delay between when you receive reputation and when your profile on other sites will display it. Waiting ~15 minutes should give it enough time to update.

Comment: Thank you. I dont know it take time to update reputation now It's OK.

Comment: If you give upvoted this question then in which account reputation incrmented?

Comment: meta actions don't affect reputation at all.

Comment: Stackexchange Data Explorer reputation also differs from Stackoverflow, any ideas?